# In Magento 1.9 home page shows the product in disorder

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

Hey I added some products to display in home page. Products are showing but in disorder that I attached photo. I did not get how to display the product in same row,[image]

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: Hi, I used default magento 1.9 function and added in admin-> cms-> pages->home pages in that I added the code is:-
    
    '<p>{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="9" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}</p>' @kunj

Comment: Ok, Magento showing last added product first.

Comment: yes, but it not showing one bye one
like in screen shot first row shows two products, in second shows one product and in third shows two product like that series generate. @kunj

Comment: Share your phtml file code.

Comment: you can see in magento 1.9.2.4 following path:- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: is this issue also in category page ? or juste in home page ?

Comment: Only in Home Page

Comment: I think it is working fine maybe issue in CSS or somehow `ul` tag not working properly. If it showing first 3 then 1 and again same then code working fine issue in CSS.